# Can my older computer be connected to a newer 32" Sony Bravia LCD television?

Tags: display, tv

I would like to connect my older computer system to my Sony Bravia LCD television.  Some system configuration info is below.

CPU:  Pentium III, 1.2 GHz
RAM:  256 MB
Motherboard:  Intel 810E

Is this possible, or might it damage the computer or television?

Comment: ya i have VGA card on both my desktop and Tv...Will it work if i connect in VGA cable.will it work fine?

Comment: yep, you might need to adjust your resolution to make it look alright, but it will work

Answer (score 2):

Does the TV have a VGA socket (Small D shaped plug with 15pins in 3rows) ?
If so then it should just work, otherwise you may need a fancier graphics card with a DVI/HDMI output.

Assuming the HW isn't faulty then no you cannot damage the TV.

Comment: There are plenty of adapters out there to change the video signal for RCA, HDMI, etc. So all he really needs is the right adapter.

Comment: An adapter is fine if it's just a connector issue. Converting VGA to composite video, hdmi or s-video requires a bit more. VGA to HDMI (or v.v.) needs almost a computer!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if they share a socket type, they will work together. If they don't both share a socket type, you may consider an adapter (ie. VGA to HDMI), however that's not guaranteed to work.